# How to add blackhole route with NetPlan on Ubuntu 20+

Tags: ubuntu, netplan

I need advice on adding a blackhole route with a localhost interface managed by Netplan.io.

My configuration that doesn't work:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernet:
        lo:
          match:
           name: lo
          routes:
           - to: 2001:db8:1::/48
             type: blackhole
             metric: 254
        enp1s0:
            accept-ra: true
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                macaddress: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
            set-name: enp1s0
            addresses:
              - 1.1.1.2/24
              - 2001:db8:1::2/64
            routes:
             - to: default
               via: 1.1.1.1
             - to: default
               via: 2001:db8:1::1
```

but at the same time, if I try to define blackhole route with a physical ethernet adapter, it magically works:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernet:
        enp1s0:
            accept-ra: true
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                macaddress: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
            set-name: enp1s0
            addresses:
              - 1.1.1.2/24
              - 2001:db8:1::2/64
            routes:
             - to: 2001:db8:1::/48
               type: blackhole
               metric: 254
             - to: default
               via: 1.1.1.1
             - to: default
               via: 2001:db8:1::1
```

What do I do wrong or suggest how to add the blackhole route another way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set *via* parameter because netplan ignore rule w/o it

Comment: Please provide more detail.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).